# How create a new FieldType in solr schema.xml

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc, solr

I'm new to Solr,
I'm  developing an application for my thesis, a kind of search semantic engine ,i use springsource, (something like that siri or s-voice). I use springsource and Solr with Indexing my documents,but i have some problem with  fieldType. My schema requires a custom model (not only a class with a string parameter):

```
public class IndexedObject{

private String id;

private ArrayList<String> features;

private ArrayList<Semantic> semantic;

private String score;

private String time;

private int status;

@XmlElement(name="time")
public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

@Field
public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

@XmlElement(name="status")
public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@XmlElement(name="score")
public String getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(String score) {
    this.score = score;
}

@XmlElement(name="id", required=true)
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

@Field
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "features")
@XmlElement(name = "feature")
public ArrayList<String> getFeatures() {
    return features;
}

@Field
public void setFeatures(ArrayList<String> features) {
    this.features = features;
}

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "semantics")
@XmlElement(name = "semantic")
public ArrayList<Semantic> getSemantic() {
    return semantic;
}

@Field
public void setSemantic(ArrayList<Semantic> semantic) {
    this.semantic = semantic;
}
```

I have a problem with ArrayList semantic that use a custom class that i wrote.
The question is: How I create a custom FieldType to add to solr schema.xml. If I start my code I get this error :solr error unknown field semantic. and it does not work.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following links for guidance on modifying the Solr Schema.

- [Documents, Fields and Schema Design](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Documents,+Fields,+and+Schema+Design)
- [Schema XML](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml)